# Trying to run ogre project in code::blocks under ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks, ogre

I was trying to get ogre working in QT Creator but was having problems. So I decided to try the code::blocks template project but I keep getting these errors:

> > ||=== ogre, Debug ===|
> >
> > ld||cannot find -lOgreMain_d|
> >
> > ld||cannot find -lOIS_d|
> >
> > ||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Seemed obvious that it could not find the ogre library so I added "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" to the library search path since that is where the ogre main .so file was located. However, it is still unable to find it. I know I'm just being stupid but please have pity on me. Also before you ask I do have the libraries installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a perfect tutorial: http://www.rdeeson.com/weblog/105/getting-set-up-with-ogre-3d-on-ubuntu.html